# How to Access Model Output's Logits in LLMChain?

Tags: nlp, classification, langchain, llama

I am working on a prediction project using llama2 with langchain.I am interested in obtaining the logits from the model's output for further analysis. Is there a way to access these logits directly from LLMChain?

I implemented the model without langchain and obtained the logits from the main model using the following code:

```
outputs = model(input_ids)
logits = outputs.logits.detach().cpu()
probs = torch.log_softmax(logits.float(), dim=-1).detach().cpu()
```

However, I want to access logit values of langchain output.

```
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["text"])
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)
```

Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: at the API level you need to check, if they have exposed this capability

Comment: I checked the documantation, couldn't find any helpful information there!